# Iterating through a siblings child classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate over the elements in one div on an onclick event inside the div without also iterating over another div with the same.

My Previous Javascript Method

```
$(document).on('click', '.ddSubmit', function() { 
     $("input[name*='ddText']").each(function() {
         $("select[name*='ddFinal']").append('<option>'+$(this).val()+'</option>');
     });
});
```

The problem in the previous example was that if I had input fields in separate divs it would iterate over every input field in all divs

My Current Javascript Method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ddSubmit', function() { 
    $(this).next('.ddP').children('.ddText').each(function() {
        $("select[name*='ddFinal']").append('<option>'+$(this).val()+'</option>');
    });   
});
```

This is the solution I came up with but it is not appending to the select element am I going about this the wrong way or is there something I'm missing

edit: Here's the fiddle I'm working on http://jsfiddle.net/me74Z/20/

Comment: Probably `$("select[name*='ddFinal']")` is not selecting any element. See the jQuery selectors' documentation.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with to my question after working on it for a while

```
$(this).parent().find('>p.ddP>input[name="ddText"]').each(function() {
    $("select[name*='ddFinal']").append('<option>'+$(this).val()+'</option>');
});
```

I went through the parent div in the debugger and traced the path to the input text elements

Answer (score 0):

Close with the first method, just use a preserved instance of `this` and you'll be all set:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ddSubmit', function() {
     var that = this;
     $("input[name*='ddText']", that).each(function() {
         $("select[name*='ddFinal']", that).append('<option>'+this.value+'</option>');
     });
});
```